Get JSON key names from a field in the database
I need to parse a JSON field obtained from a PostgreSQL database. Moreover, I do not know in advance what field names are available in JSON. I wrote the code:
        cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
        postgreSQL_select_Query = 'select body from elma365.head."abbott:Account" limit 1 '
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query
    mobile_records = cursor.fetchall()
    datajs=json.dumps(mobile_records,indent=2)
    dict = json.loads(datajs)


I get the field data, but I can't get the field names in JSON. I have tried different ways, but I have a mistake, when try print(dict.keys()):
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'


And i try some others ways:
        dataheader=ast.literal_eval(str(datajs))
    header = list(ast.literal_eval(dict).keys())

But have errors.
Could you tell me how to get the names of the JSON fields anyway?
I have tried different ways, but I have a mistake, when try print(dict.keys()):
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'


And i try some others ways:
        dataheader=ast.literal_eval(str(datajs))
    header = list(ast.literal_eval(dict).keys())

But have errors.
